# Function in PHP not working

Tags: php

I have this php code which takes in elements from an array and arranges the values into divs (the code starts a new row after every 3 items):

```
    <?php

function display_products($product_id, $product){

$count = 0;
$output = "";

foreach($products as $product_id => $product) {

    if (++$count % 3 == 1){
        $output = $output . '<div class="offset1 span3">';
    }
    else {
        $output = $output . '<div class="span3">';
    }

$output = $output . '<div class="centre">';
$output = $output . '<a href="product.php?id=' . $product_id . '"><img src="' .              $product["img"] . '" alt="' . $product["name"] . '"></a>';
$output = $output . "</div>";
$output = $output . "</div>";

    if (++$count % 3 == 0) {
        $output = $output . "</div> <div class='row-fluid'>";
    }

 }

 return $output;    
    }

$products = array();

$products[101] = array(
    "name" => "My Product",
    "img" => "img/product1.jpg"
);
?>
```

and have linked to this file in my index.php file like this:

```
          <div class="row-fluid">

<?php 
    echo display_products($product_id, $product);
?>

</div>
```

my problem is, the function doesn't work. The code worked fine before I pasted it into the function.

Comment: Is the function in your `index.php` file?

Comment: Any errors you're getting?

Comment: ^--- if the function is not inside index.php, you have to include it  like.. `include "function.display_products.php"`

Comment: Is the function being passed the correct parameters?

Comment: The function is in a separate file where I keep the array. I included it in my index.php file with  include('inc/products.php');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining the second variable passed into your function to be named `$product`, then using `$products` to loop through (which won't exist).

Should be:

```
function display_products($product_id, $products){
    ...
    foreach($products as $product_id => $product) {
```